# How can I connect to an HSQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, hsqldb

I would like to manipulate an HSQL database using PHP. I have [read the documentation regarding HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_connecting_db) and it only shows an example of connecting using Java. How can I connect to an HSQL database in PHP?

Comment: just do some googling! https://coderanch.com/t/631003/Accessing-file-system-HSQLDB-PHP

Comment: I have done some, your link basically just said it was impossible and to use SQLite instead. But I already have an HSQL database filled and would like to use it, which is why I posted here.

Comment: ya sorry  you are right! ;))

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf The OP is not asking for MySQL but HyperSQL. So not a dupe. At least not of that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ODBC driver for HSQLDB. The installer is available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/alpha_beta/).

Comment: This is a help, but do you know if the sources are available for other operating systems? e.g. CentOS.

Comment: Sources are in version control system https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/svn/HEAD/tree/odbc/